# How to handle parsing numbers with same catch block?

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

I come across a situation quite often where I need to parse a numerical value (e.g. with Integer.parseInt or Double.parseDouble) and I have multiple values. The problem is that I find myself having to duplicate the exception-handling and it becomes ugly. For instance, take the following code:

```
double lowVal, mediumVal, highVal;
String lowString = "1.2", mediumString = "null", highString = "7.9";

try {
    lowVal = parseDouble(lowString);
} catch (NumberFormatException NaN) {
    //Don't care, just carry on trying to parse the rest...
}

try {
    mediumVal = parseDouble(mediumString);
} catch (NumberFormatException NaN) {
    //Don't care, just carry on trying to parse the rest...
}

try {
    highVal = parseDouble(highString);
} catch (NumberFormatException NaN) {
    //Don't care, just carry on trying to parse the rest...
}
```

Is there a good pattern for dealing with this situation?

I don't want to use a single-try catch because I want to continue parsing the rest of the numbers.

I should mention that in this example, the values are not initialized but in actual program code they would be. The assignment should only occur if the string values are parseable.

Comment: just use one try-catch for all three

Comment: But i want the rest to continue executing. If you try to parse all of them in the same try block, whenever an exception is thrown, how can you continue parsing the rest?

Comment: Maybe put the single try-catch within a loop with flags that prevent the last exception that is thrown from executing again.

Comment: I see. You can't continue parsing; that is the problem with RuntimeExceptions, you either halt or catch every individual one.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what you want to assign to `lowVal` and friends if the parsing fails. You can't just "not care", because the code above won't even compile. It will complain that lowVal is possibly uninitialized: since if the parseDouble fails, it will throw before any value is assigned and then you catch the exception, leaving an uninitialized `lowVal` in scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just extract a method:

```
double lowVal, mediumVal, highVal;
String lowString = "1.2", mediumString = "null", highString = "7.9";

lowVal = parseDouble(lowString);
mediumVal = parseDouble(mediumString);
highVal = parseDouble(highString);

double parseDouble(String s) {
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return Double.NAN;
    } 
}
```

or

```
Double lowVal;
Double mediumVal;
Double highVal;
String lowString = "1.2", mediumString = "null", highString = "7.9";

lowVal = parseDouble(lowString);
mediumVal = parseDouble(mediumString);
highVal = parseDouble(highString);

Double parseDouble(String s) {
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't want to assign the value if it's not valid though.

Comment: @SinaMadani the `double` primitive defaults to a value of `0.0`, so it will have a value anyway

Comment: The value may already have been assigned somewhere else in the code, I was just using this as a simple example. I suppose I could pass in the current value and use that as the return value.

Answer (score 1):

In the docs of [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) you have the solution to your problem.

> To avoid calling this method on an invalid string and having a NumberFormatException be thrown, the regular expression below can be used to screen the input string

Wrap everything in your parseDouble method and follow the instructions

```
if (Pattern.matches(fpRegex, myString))
            Double.valueOf(myString); // Will not throw NumberFormatException
        else {
            // Perform suitable alternative action
        }
```

Which from your question seems to be replacing it by another comment

```
//Don't care, just carry on trying to parse the rest...
```

In case the link becomes innactive (should never happen) this is the regex

```
final String Digits     = "(\\p{Digit}+)";
final String HexDigits  = "(\\p{XDigit}+)";
    // an exponent is 'e' or 'E' followed by an optionally 
    // signed decimal integer.
    final String Exp        = "[eE][+-]?"+Digits;
    final String fpRegex    =
        ("[\\x00-\\x20]*"+  // Optional leading "whitespace"
         "[+-]?(" + // Optional sign character
         "NaN|" +           // "NaN" string
         "Infinity|" +      // "Infinity" string

         // A decimal floating-point string representing a finite positive
         // number without a leading sign has at most five basic pieces:
         // Digits . Digits ExponentPart FloatTypeSuffix
         // 
         // Since this method allows integer-only strings as input
         // in addition to strings of floating-point literals, the
         // two sub-patterns below are simplifications of the grammar
         // productions from the Java Language Specification, 2nd 
         // edition, section 3.10.2.

         // Digits ._opt Digits_opt ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
         "((("+Digits+"(\\.)?("+Digits+"?)("+Exp+")?)|"+

         // . Digits ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
         "(\\.("+Digits+")("+Exp+")?)|"+

   // Hexadecimal strings
   "((" +
    // 0[xX] HexDigits ._opt BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
    "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "(\\.)?)|" +

    // 0[xX] HexDigits_opt . HexDigits BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
    "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "?(\\.)" + HexDigits + ")" +

    ")[pP][+-]?" + Digits + "))" +
         "[fFdD]?))" +
         "[\\x00-\\x20]*");// Optional trailing "whitespace"
```

Comment: Where can I find "fpRegex"?

Comment: Click on the link named Double. It has the entire code you need

Comment: The regex is fairly ugly so I think I prefer other methods. Good alternative though.

Comment: You stash it in a method and you never have to see its ugly face again :)

Comment: But then why not use a dedicated method for parsing in the first place (to avoid the if statement)?

Comment: Why not use a try-catch then? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a class like this:

```
class DoubleParser {

    private Optional<Double> parsedOptional;

    private DoubleParser(Optional<Double> parsedOptional) {
        this.parsedOptional = parsedOptional;
    }

    public static DoubleParser parse(final String s) {
        Double parsed = null;
        try {
            parsed = Double.valueOf(s);
        } catch ( NumberFormatException e ) {
            parsed = null;
        }

        return new DoubleParser(Optional.ofNullable(parsed));
    }

    public double get() {
        return get(0.0);
    }

    public double get(final double defaultValue) {
        return parsedOptional.orElse(defaultValue);
    }

}
```

And then use it like this:

```
double lowVal, mediumVal, highVal;
String lowString = "1.2", mediumString = "null", highString = "7.9";

lowVal = DoubleParser.parse(lowString).get();
mediumVal = DoubleParser.parse(mediumString).get();
highVal = DoubleParser.parse(highString).get();

// with default value if you want
mediumVal = DoubleParser.parse(mediumString).get(Double.NaN);
```

Comment: Good solution, but unfortunately I can't use this in Android because it doesn't support Java 8.

Comment: @SinaMadani my bad, can't wait Java 8 on Android myself

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a single try-catch for all your values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using flags and a loop to prevent the exceptions from occurring again:

```
    double lowVal, mediumVal, highVal;
    String lowString = "1.2", mediumString = "null", highString = "7.9";
    int count = 0;
    boolean lowFlag = false, medFlag = false, highFlag = false;
    do{
        try {
            count = 0;
            count++;
            if(!lowFlag)
                lowVal = parseDouble(lowString);
            count++;
            if(!medFlag)
                mediumVal = parseDouble(mediumString);
            count++;
            if(!highFlag)
                highVal = parseDouble(highString);

            break;

        } catch (NumberFormatException NaN) {
            if(count==0)
                lowFlag = true;
            else if(count==1)
                medFlag = true;
            else if(count==2)
                highFlag = true;
        }
    }while(true);
```

Comment: The problem is that of verbosity. I don't mind having empty catch blocks but I was hoping for a solution that would reduce the code, not increase it.

Answer (score 0):

When you expect parsing failures, I find it simpler not to use the exception based methods at all. In addition to leading to more concise code, it can be several orders of magnitude faster since it avoids the expense of throwing exceptions.

Rather than writing my own methods, it's Guava to the rescue as usual. You can rewrite your parsing with [Doubles.tryParse](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#tryParse%28java.lang.String%29) like so:

```
Double lowVal, mediumVal, highVal;
String lowString = "1.2", mediumString = "null", highString = "7.9";    

lowVal = Doubles.tryParse(lowString);  
mediumVal = Doubles.tryParse(mediumString);
highVal = Doubles.tryParse(highString);
```

Very concise! Note that any values that couldn't be parsed will be `null` after this executes. You haven't actually said what value you want to assign to the Doubles if the parsing fails (and in fact your original example won't compile since the values are potentially uninitialized).

Let's assume you wanted to assign the value 0.0 to any failed parsing - you could use [Objects.firstNonNull()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull%28T,%20T%29) to do that:

```
Double lowVal, mediumVal, highVal;
String lowString = "1.2", mediumString = "null", highString = "7.9";    

lowVal = Objects.firstNonNull(Doubles.tryParse(lowString), 0.0);  
mediumVal = Objects.firstNonNull(Doubles.tryParse(mediumString), 0.0);
highVal = Objects.firstNonNull(Doubles.tryParse(highString), 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use this method:

```
public static double parseWithDefault(String value, double fallback) {
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException NaN) {
        return fallback;
    }
}
```

And then can make assignments like so:

```
lowVal = parseWithDefault(lowString, lowVal);
mediumVal = parseWithDefault(mediumString, mediumVal);
highVal = parseWithDefault(highString, highVal);
```